# Paypal Notify Url Not being called

Tags: asp.net

I have both "Personal" and "Business" accounts in Paypal sandbox. I have set and enabled notify url from my profile settings of business account.Payment is successfully done, but notify url page is not being called, so the email generated in pageload of notify url page is not received to me.This same page generates email when return url calls it, but donot generate email by notify url(not being called). I am using asp.net (C#). Plzzz help me i am really tired by searching, but failed. plz help me.

Comment: please paste some code, so that we can figure out your problem

Comment: Hay guys finally i got the solution. It was nothing, just that our payment page as well as IPN page, both should be uploaded on server even for testing. remember "Both Pages". Not only IPN page.

Comment: You should make this as your answer of your own question.